# use Row_number after applying distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, paging

I am creating an SP which gives some result by applying distinct on it, now I want to implement sever side paging, so I tried using Row_number on distinct result like:

```
    WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tblA.TeamName DESC)
as Row,tblA.TeamId,tblA.TeamName,tblA.CompId,tblA.CompName,tblA.Title,tblA.Thumbnail,tblA.Rank,tblA.CountryId,tblA.CountryName
         FROM
         (
           --The table query starts with SELECT 
         )tblA
    )
        SELECT CTE.* FROM CTE
        WHERE CTE.Row BETWEEN @StartRowIndex AND @StartRowIndex+@NumRows-1
        ORDER BY CTE.CountryName
```

but rows are first assigned RowNumber then distinct get applied that is why I am getting duplicate values, how to get distinct rows first then get row numbers for the same.

Any solution on this? Am I missing something?
need answer ASAP.
thanks in advance!

Comment: The "DISTINCT" keyword is not present in your query. Are you sure you are using DISTINCT?

Comment: hey Mark, m sorry, I forgot to verify, there is a business logic query  ( --The table query starts with SELECT )tblA where I have used DISTINCT keyword. and It works well when executed indivisually

Comment: Try posting your full query because i cannot make anything of it now.

Comment: can you give an exact example with out put what exactly you want in output so it will be clear to understand and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to add "partition by" to your ROW_NUMBER statement?

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by ___, ___, ORDER BY tblA.TeamName DESC)
```

In the blank spaces, place the column names you would like to create a new row number for. Duplicates will receive a number that is NOT 1 so you might not need the distinct.

To gather the unique values you could write a subquery where the stored procedure only grabs the rows with a 1 in them.

```
select * from
(
  your code
) where row = 1
```

Hope that helps.

I'm not sure why you're doing this:

```
WHERE CTE.Row BETWEEN @StartRowIndex AND @StartRowIndex+@NumRows-1
```